# Working with exporting PATH CentOS strange behaviour

Tags: shell, path, profile

I am trying to modify the `PATH` variable in two different scripts
located in `/etc/profile.d/`

- `/etc/profile.d/php.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php/bin
  export PATH
  ```
- `/etc/profile.d/mysql.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
  export PATH
  ```

Restarting CentOS and checking the `PATH` variable (edited),
the $PATH is modified twice!

```
[]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/php/bin:/home/IntUser/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:
/usr/local/php/bin
[]$
```

In root mode:

```
[]$ su
Password: 
[]#
```

The $PATH is modified 3 times!

```
[]# echo $PATH
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/php/bin:/home/IntUser/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:
/usr/local/php/bin:/usr/local//mysql/bin:/usr/local/php/bin
[]#
```

Why is it not assigned only one time?

Comment: Try to trace bash start up: `bash -lvx -c true >log 2>&1`.  See `log` to find where it updates `PATH`.

Comment: Does PATH already contain those directories before you add them? Also, each new bash shell loads the profile scripts, so that's why you see them added to the end again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix: replace your file `/etc/profile.d/php.sh` contents with:

```
pathmunge /usr/local/php/bin after
```

and similarly for the file `/etc/profile.d/mysql.sh`:

```
pathmunge /usr/local/mysql/bin after
```

The explanation is that 
the files in /etc/profile.d/*.sh are **sourced** by 
`/etc/profile` (which is itself sourced by a login bash shell).

Because the files are sourced, it is as they were part of `/etc/profile` so
they can use any variables and functions in that file. `pathmunge` is such
a function (on my fedora 20 anyway), whose sole purpose is to add a new
directory to the `PATH`, but only if it is not already there. The keyword
`after` adds the new directory to the end of the `PATH`.

Hence you will have no duplicates. However, I do not know why you have them
in the first place.

Comment: Yes, `pathmunge` was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because something in your configuration is loading `/etc/profile` multiple times. You need to locate it and fix it.

The file `/etc/profile` is read by a login shell. It's also read when logging in to a graphical session on many platforms (but it depends on the display manager, on the session manager, and on how your distribution set them up).

One possible problem is that you're requesting `/etc/profile` to be read from some other location such as `~/.bashrc`. If that's the case, remove it. Run `grep -s profile ~/.*` to see potential offenders. Since running `su` reads `/etc/profile`, there has to be at least one instance of that problem, probably with `.bashrc`.

Another possible problem is if you run a login shell when you open a terminal in a GUI session. The fix is then not to run a login shell — you're already logged in to the GUI session, the terminal is an ordinary application.

Given that you have one occurrence of the directories before `/home/IntUser/bin` and another one after, `/etc/profile` is getting read a second time after the part that adds `/home/IntUser/bin`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to fix your configuration, you could add the directory to the PATH only if it isn't there already.

```
case :$PATH: in
  *:/usr/local/php/bin:*) :;;
  *) PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php/bin;;
esac
```

Comment: I was testing your script, bhut the result is equal...